# select up to N (random, or the N first) rows for each unique values of a column using unix or awk (no sql)

Tags: unix, select, awk, unique, rows

would anyone know how to select *up to N (random, or the N first) rows* for each unique values of a column, using unix command (or sed, awk etc)? Please no SQL as I don't know this langage.

Thank you very much for your help!
Carole

here is an example input file:

```
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
6   00108.padded.fasta  2348
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
```

I would like to extract up to N rows (let's say up to 2 for this example) for each given unique value in column 2:
expected output:

```
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
6   00108.padded.fasta  2348
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
```

Here I chose the first two rows, but it could be a randomly chosen pair of rows for each unique value in column 2.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you're looking for? Like a sample input file and what the output would look like for a particular set of parameters?

Comment: You want to extract, say, 2 rows. What if there's only one row for a given unique value in column 2?

Answer (score 0):

This will return a constant number of rows (two in this case) for each unique value in column 2, but I'm pretty sure this isn't quite what you expected. Your input data is in the file 'test.txt'.

```
$ sort -k2 -u test.txt > a.tmp; sort a.tmp a.tmp
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
6   00108.padded.fasta  2348
6   00108.padded.fasta  2348
```

It's not clear what you expect if your input has only one row for a given unique value in column 2. If you still want two rows in the output, then this will work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. To answer your question: I should have said I want to extract *up to N rows* for each given unique value in column 2, i.e. if N=2 and there is only one row for a given unique value in column 2, I would like to output this only one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# tested with bash 4
declare -A assoc
declare -a count
while read -r line
do
    array=($line)
    assoc[ ${array[0]} ]+="${array[@]}|"
done < file
OIFS=$IFS
IFS="|"
for i in "${!assoc[@]}"
do
    count=(${assoc[$i]})
    echo "${count[@]:0:2}"
done
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

@carol, this is my output using your sample data. I use bash 4+. If you don't have it, then it won't work with associative arrays.

```
bash4> bash N.sh
6 00108.padded.fasta 2348 6 00108.padded.fasta 2348
3 00017.padded.fasta 1769 3 00017.padded.fasta 1769
5 00059.padded.fasta 2986 5 00059.padded.fasta 2986
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I can't make this work. I replaced 'file' by my input file, but if I run it as row.sh > output.txt it gives an empty output file. Moreover, I added a precision in my question: if N=2 but for one given unique value in column 2, I have only one row, it should output this single row. so it is 'up to N' rather than N. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

here is a small script for your purpose:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

awk '{ print $0 >$2".yourfile"}' yourfile
for i in *.yourfile
do
awk 'NR<=2{print}' $i
done
rm -rf *.yourfile
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "remove temp files successful"
fi
```

here is the execution:

```
torinoco!DBL:/oo_dgfqausr/test/dfqwrk12/vijay> script.sh
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
6   00108.padded.fasta  2348
remove temp files successful
torinoco!DBL:/oo_dgfqausr/test/dfqwrk12/vijay>
```

Comment: hi. Thanks for this script. I tried it but it did not work. Must have done something wrong, but I am beginner so...here is what I run: awk '{ print $0 >$2 }' row.txt
for i in row.txt
do
awk 'NR<=4{print}' $i
done
rm -rf row.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "remove temp files successful"
fi                           just obtained the same info as in the input file, so no selection of 4 rows for each given unique value in column 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is my file test.awk.

```
$1 >= n {$1 = n;}
$1 <  n {$1 = $1;}
{
    for (i = 1; i<= $1; i++) {
      print $0;
    }
}
```

Here's my version of test.txt. Assumes your test data is representative.

```
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
5   00059.padded.fasta  2986
6   00108.padded.fasta  2348
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
3   00017.padded.fasta  1769
1   00001.padded.fasta  1000
```

And this is the command line that gives you up to 'n' lines of output.

```
$ sort test.txt | uniq -c | awk -v n=2 -f test.awk  | cut -f 1 -d " " --complement
1 00001.padded.fasta 1000
3 00017.padded.fasta 1769
3 00017.padded.fasta 1769
5 00059.padded.fasta 2986
5 00059.padded.fasta 2986
6 00108.padded.fasta 2348
```

To change the number of lines, change the value assigned to 'n'. n=4, n=3, etc.